# computed binding updates when function changes, is it a feature?

Tags: polymer-1.0

When I was looking for a way to have Polymer 1.0 update a computed binding, I noticed that when I declared the computing function as a property, setting the property value to a new function does update. Can I rely on that behavior or is it a coincidence?

```
<dom-module id="flip-fn">
<template>
<p on-tap="flip">{{fn()}}</p>
</template>
<script>
(function(){
  function fn1(){return 'val1';}
  function fn2(){return 'val2';}
  Polymer({
    is: 'flip-fn',
    properties:{
      fn: {type: Object, value:function(){return fn1;}}
    },
    flip:function(){
      this.fn = fn2;
    }
  });
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Noticeably, when I use that computed binding in a dom-if it does not work:

```
...
<p on-tap="flip">{{fn()}}</p> <!-- this works -->
<template is="dom-if" if="true">
  <p>{{fn()}}</p>             <!-- does not show any text -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rely on it.

The example https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dynamic-sort-and-filter-changes uses dynamic filter that also uses this feature.

A function reference is also just an object. When polymer checks identity, it gets a false if it refers a different function and has to treat it as change.